# Calculate total additions and subtractions from inventory per user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a device that audits all inventory transactions to an t-sql database. I need a select statement that will generate how many additions and subtractions a user performed on inventory (we don't care what parts are involved, just an overall total of transactions). The table looks like:

```
userName   partNum  LastOHQ   NewOHQ
_____________________________________
joeShmoe    667-5     52        60
lazyP       664-2     88        44
joeShmoe    89-66     78        22
jesseJames  100-1     19        99
```

now, given the usage of basic mathematics i'm able to determine if a transaction was adding into inventory, or removed by using [NewOHQ - LastOHQ = ?], if the number is positive, i know it was added, if negative, it was removed.

how can i create a result set like:

```
userName    added   subtracted
______________________________
joeShmoe       8        56
lazyP         0        44
jesseJames    80       0
```

~SQL novice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use some `CASE` expressions to create your calculated columns.

```
SELECT userName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN NewOHQ - LastOHQ > 0 THEN NewOHQ - LastOHQ
         ELSE 0 END) added,
    SUM(CASE WHEN NewOHQ - LastOHQ < 0 THEN LastOHQ - NewOHQ
         ELSE 0 END) subtracted
FROM InventoryTransactions
GROUP BY userName
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a2ab/5) that shows your example.

Comment: Technically, they're *expressions* rather than *statements* because they produce *values*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good call. I threw that sentence together in a hurry.